# Axis2 wsdl2java - parse error

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate java classes from wsdl file. Originally this file was used with Axis 1.1 with no problems. Then Axis1 was replaced with Axis2 and now generation isn't working with the following error:

> ```
>  [java] Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerat
> ```
>
> ionException: Error parsing WSDL
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(Cod
>   eGenerationEngine.java:175)
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
>        [java] Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: There are no parts for fault
>   message : {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}createPolicyCustomLSPDTOFault
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.popul
>   ateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:411)
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.p
>   opulateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:107)
>        [java]     at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(Cod
>   eGenerationEngine.java:169)
>        [java]     ... 2 more

Faulting line from wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:operation name="createPolicyCustomLSPDTO">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:createPolicyCustomLSPDTORequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:createPolicyCustomLSPDTOResponse"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="Fault" message="tns:createPolicyCustomLSPDTOFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

createPolicyCustomLSPDTOFault is defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://webservice.example.com"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:hql="http://hql.webservice.example.com"
    targetNamespace="http://webservice.example.com"
>

    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.example.com" schemaLocation="ServerMessageDTO.xsd"/>
        <xsd:schema
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://webservice.example.com"
        >
            <xsd:element name="createPolicyCustomLSPDTOFault" type="tns:ServerMessageDTO"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```

How do I fix this?